# Populating tabular with etoolbox list

Tags: tables, etoolbox, token-lists

I am trying to populate a `tabular` environment with an etoolbox list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\listadd\mylist{Ana}%
\listadd\mylist{Bob}%
\listadd\mylist{Cole}%

\newcommand*{\pco}{%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{Person: & ##1 \\}
    \dolistloop{\mylist}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r | l}
        \pco
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I meant for this to generate a table like:

```
Person: | Ana
Person: | Bob
Person: | Cole
```

Instead, I got:

```
Person: | Ana
BobCole |
```

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. My first thought was that the `\do` command is being understood by the table as a single token (i.e. `{Person: & ##1 \\}`). But in the first instance that's not the case: the first item on the list is successfully split into two columns. However, the following items aren't; indeed, `\do` seems to be ignored entirely, and the value of each list item is simply being printed.

What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that `\pco` is called within the first cell of the table. This means the redefinition of `\do` is forgotten after the first cell ends (cells form groups)… This is why the suggestion with`\forlistloop` works: the definition of `\pcodo` is *outside* of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\forlistloop` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\pcodo}[1]{Person: & #1 \\}

\listadd\mylist{Ana}
\listadd\mylist{Bob}
\listadd\mylist{Cole}

\newcommand*{\pco}{\forlistloop{\pcodo}{\mylist}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r | l}
\pco
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

There are better ways, though. Here's an implementation that's similar to the one with `\xintFor`, but allows for incrementally building the list.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% initialize a list
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{m}
 { % #1=list name
  \seq_new:c { g_wasabi_list_#1_seq }
 }

% populate a list one item at a time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_wasabi_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

% use a list; "pre" and "post" are code executed before and after the loop
\NewDocumentCommand{\uselist}{mO{}mO{}}
 { % #1=list name, #2=pre, #3=template, #4=post
  \cs_gset:Nn \__wasabi_list_temp:n { #3 }
  #2
  \seq_map_function:cN { g_wasabi_list_#1_seq } \__wasabi_list_temp:n
  #4
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{my}

%% these commands can go anywhere, provided they are before
%% using the list
\addtolist{my}{Ana}
\addtolist{my}{Bob}
\addtolist{my}{Cole}

\begin{document}

\uselist{my}
  [\begin{tabular}{r|l}]
  {Person & #1 \\}
  [\end{tabular}]

\bigskip

\uselist{my}{#1, }

\end{document}
```

A list can be used in several ways, with different templates.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tabular`s, it is often easier to build up (i.e., successively concatenate) a token list and then dump it into the input stream at the end of the process.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\listadd\mylist{Ana}%
\listadd\mylist{Bob}%
\listadd\mylist{Cole}%

\newtoks\tabtoks
\newcommand*{\pco}{%
    \tabtoks{}%
    \newcommand*{\ZaZa}[1]{\tabtoks\expandafter{\the\tabtoks Person: & ##1 \\}}%
    \forlistloop\ZaZa{\mylist}%
    \the\tabtoks%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r | l}
        \pco
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, thanks to jfbu for noting the problem can be solved more simply than that.  The problem with the OP's code is that the `&` column separator creates a different scope under `\halign`, and so one must work within that constraint of making things globally available to the other `tabular` cells.  For example, in the OP's original code, merely changing `\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{Person: & ##1 \\}` to `\gdef\do##1{Person: & ##1 \\}`  makes the code produce the proper output.  However, thanks to egreg for noting that redefining `\do` globally is not acceptable and pointing to `\forlistloop` as the optimal alternative.

jfbu proposed the following resolution:

```
\newcommand*{\pco}{%
  \gdef\ZaZa##1{Person: & ##1 \\}%
  \forlistloop\ZaZa{\mylist}%
}
```

resulting in code that works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\listadd\mylist{Ana}%
\listadd\mylist{Bob}%
\listadd\mylist{Cole}%

\newcommand*{\pco}{%
  \gdef\ZaZa##1{Person: & ##1 \\}%
  \forlistloop\ZaZa{\mylist}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r | l}
        \pco
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @jfbu Do you wish to set a different answer, or for me to add your point to this one?  I recommend you provide a separate answer, as I could not do the explanation justice.

Comment: well done ;-) ...

Comment: Doing `\gdef\do` is wrong, sorry. It's a local scratch macro and should remain such.

Comment: @egreg Would `\let\svdo\do%` before the `tabular` and `\let\do\svdo%` afterwards satisfy the need?  Also, that would not be needed in the `\tabtoks` approach, since the scope is limited there...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No. But you can use a different macro with more advanced list management in `etoolbox`.

Comment: `\gdef\ZaZa##1{Person: & ##1 \\}%`, `\forlistloop\ZaZa{\mylist}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes sorry for you green tick... I think your answer contains more information than the accepted one. Sure the `\do` remark by egreg is fully justified, but here it was initally about explaining what was wrong in OP's code...

Comment: @jfbu I rolled back my answer and edited so as to preserve your good explanation.

Comment: now that we have our `ZaZa` via a `\gdef` it may have well be defined outside of the scope, but then we end up with egreg's answer... ;-)

Comment: @jfbu Well, we live in an imperfect world...

Comment: let's remain immune to unjust turn of events ;-) accepted answer is good one, but a bit dry ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Alongside the excellent other two answers, I can propose this one which needs no definition of an extra macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand\mylist{Ana, Bob, Cole}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r | l}
        \xintFor #1 in \mylist \do{Person: & #1 \\}
    \end{tabular}

% or \xintFor #1 in {Ana, Bob, Cole}
% or \xintFor* #1 in {{Ana}{Bob}{Cole}}
\end{document}
```